# Find location of character index in a Swing text control

Tags: java, swing, model, jtextcomponent, swing-highlighter

I want to do some custom drawing of brackets around certain text in a text control in Java Swing. But I need to know where to draw them. I do know the exact range of characters in the text content, so I just need to be able to translate those indexes into specific locations on the control so I can draw.

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: question, by using JTextComponents API, or Graphics API

Comment: @mKorbel Whichever will get me what I need.

Comment: you can to use JTextComponets#viewToModel (JTextPane / JEditorPane) for HightLighter, sorry I'm very bad in Graphics, but there must be something similair as params for drawString(x, x, x) and/or with fillRect(x, x, x, x)

Comment: @mKorbel viewToModel does exactly what I need. I didn't expect it to make it so easy. Change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: don't for get to override Caret and its possition.bias for mouse event, maybe no required in your case :-), glad if help yout